# Opencart Internet Server Error on admin dashboard

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I really don't know what happened when I moved to new hosting. when I access to admin dashboard it show something like the following picture

[image]

I have no idea about this. Please help!!!

Comment: Did you specified the correct paths, and changed the database name accordingly?

Comment: Might be your admin email settings incorrect (as per new server)..